# Allow new record of duplicated cell value if a cell is null

Tags: ms-access

[image: Example]

Above is a table that shows what I want to prevent. It allows the entry of a record where the same machine, 1, is related to two contracts at the same time. How do I make a table where I can only insert a new record if all other records with the same idMachine have the cell contracEnded NOT NULL? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a form to enter your data (which you should be) you could try putting the following VBA code in the BeforeUpdate event of the control you are using to enter the data. Here I'm assuming this control is a text box named `txtIdMachine`, which is bound to the `idMachine` field in your table (which I'm assuming is named `tblMachines`).

```
Private Sub txtIdMachine_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    Dim numMachines As Integer, numEnded As Integer

    numMachines = DCount("idMachine", "tblMachines", _
        "idMachine = " & Me.txtIdMachine)
    numEnded = DCount("*", "tblMachines", _
        "contractEnded Is Not Null And idMachine = " & Me.txtIdMachine)
    If (numMachines - numEnded > 0) Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Machine " & Me.txtIdMachine & " is already in use." & _
            vbNewLine & "Select a new machine."
    End If
End Sub
```

The `DCount(A,B,C)` function will return the number of matching entries from field `A` in a table or query `B` that matches the search string `C` (basically the WHERE clause from an SQL query). `A,B,C` are strings. The `"*"` tells it to search all columns.

In the end you just have to subtract the number of instances of the machine number the user is trying to enter `Me.txtIdMachine` from the number of non-Null end dates for that machine, and check to see if there are any `idMachine` without an end date. Since it's done `BeforeUpdate`, the current entry doesn't exist yet, so it doesn't count.